# quiz ; does this compile and if so what does it return (I know the answer)

Tags: c++

I found this typo recently:

```
 if (name.find('/' != string::npos))
```

Obviously the dev meant to type

```
if(name.find('/') != string::npos)
```

But I was amazed that to find that the error even compiles with `-Wall -Werror` (didnt try with `-pedantic`)

So, coffee quiz: does it evaluate to true or false?

Comment: Please assure us that wasn't **your** atrocious uncommented code.

Comment: no - although i did cut and paste it to do the same test with a different char and then a code reviewer of my change pointed it out; so i guess its partly mine.

Comment: He provided one line. If you require a comment after every line, I'm glad I don't work with you.

Comment: C? How can this be a C code? I'm already shocked to learn a C compiler can compile this.

Comment: @Dennis - if every line is that convoluted, yes, comments please, and an asprin.

Comment: @rlb.usa: To be fair, it's not tat convoluted. It's unorthodox, sure, but easily readable.

Comment: @pm100 why did you edit your/ **the** answer into the question?

Comment: `bool false -> int = 1` .... ?? in what universe? Also, `/` is indeed different from -1 so you'll get `true`. I guess two wrongs make a right.

Comment: `string::npos` isn't "usually" -1. It's *always* -1. Why? Because the standard specifies `string::npos` holds the largest value a `size_t` (an unsigned integral type) can hold.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Which isn't necessarily -1. :P (Yes, yes, pedantic. But 1's compliment exists too! :[ )

Comment: @willhelmtell: And where does it specify that the largest value an unsigned integral type becomes -1 when converted to a signed int? The standard doesn't require two's complement.

Comment: @wilhelmtell that's not senseful. How is `-1` the largest possible value of a `size_t`? It isn't even greater than `0`. There is no `size_t` value of `-1`. Smallest one is `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'/' doesn't equal string::npos since npos is required to be negative, and none of the characters in the basic execution character set is allowed to be negative. Therefore, it's going to look for a value of `1` in the string (presumably a string anyway) represented by `name`. That's a pretty unusual value to have in a string, so it's usually not going to find it, which means it'll return `std::string::npos`, which will convert to `true`.

Edit: as Johannes pointed out, although the value assigned to npos must be negative 1 (as per 21.3/6) that's being assigned to a size_type, which must be unsigned, so the result won't be negative. This wouldn't normally make any real difference though -- the '/' would be compared to `npos` using unsigned arithmetic, so the only way they could have the same value would be if 1) '/' was encoded as -1 (not allowed as above) or char had the same range as size_type.

In theory, the standard allows char to have the same range as other integral types. In fact, quite a bit of I/O depends on EOF having a value that couldn't originate from the file, which basically translates to a requirement that char have a range that's *smaller* than int, not just smaller than or equal to (as the standard directly requires).

That does leave one loophole, though it's one that would generally be quite horrible: that char and short have the same range, size_type is the same as unsigned short, and int has a greater range than char/short. Giving char and short the same range wouldn't be all that horrible, but restricting size_type to the same range as short normally would be -- in a typical case, short is 16 bits, so it would restrict containers to 64K. That kind of restriction was problematic 20 years ago under MS-DOS; it simply wouldn't be accepted in most markets today.

Comment: "since npos is required to be negative", not true. It's required to be the highest possible (= positive) value of `size_type`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if `name` *starts* with a `char` equal to 1.

You shouldn't be amazed it compiles, there's nothing wrong about it. `'/' != std::string:npos` evaluates to true, and the only overload of `find` that would work is the `char c, size_t pos` version, as `bool` can be converted to an integer 1.

So now we're looking for `(char)1`, and what that returns depends on the string. If it starts with `(char)1`, it returns 0 and that's false. In any other case, it returns a non-zero integer, or true.

Comment: `name` doesn't need to _start_ with 1. It just has to include it somewhere in the string.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: How so? If it starts with it, it returns 0. Otherwise it returns a positive integer.

Comment: if `name` doesn't include 1 then `string::find()` returns a negative integer.

Comment: Oh wait. As a `size_t` it's still positive. :s  I'll just go ... there ... at the corner ... if anyone needs me.

Answer (score 1):

'/' != string::npos evaluates to true.  true is promoted to int (value = 1).  find probably doesn't find a value of 1.  if expression probably returns string::npos, which is typically -1, which is not zero, and is therefore true.  My guess: true.

Comment: there's no overload of string::find that takes an int. there's one that takes a char and an optional size. there are also a couple that take a pointer as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say false, unless name contains a char with value 0x01.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the implicit cast from bool to char doesn't emit a warning... as far as I can tell, it'll return true unless name begins with '\001'.

Answer (score 0):

It will evaluate to true if name contains a char == SOH

otherwise false

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted the correct answer already: The result of the boolean expression should be 1 (a truth value), because `'/'` should have a value smaller than the unsigned `string::npos` (defined to be the largest value a `size_t` can hold). Because 1 is an integer, and because 1 can't possibly be an address, the compiler finds the only overload of `string::find()` it can call is the one with `char c, size_t pos`.

But that's not the end of the story. Try to change the boolean expression from `'/' != string::npos` to `'/' == string::npos`. Now the result of the expression is 0, again an integer. Because there is no overload for `string::find()` that takes an `int`, the compiler must cast 0 -- but to what? It can cast it to a `char` and it can cast it to a pointer. Both are valid choices, so that's an ambiguous call.

So there you go: your code changes from a valid warning-free function call to an ambiguous function call by changing an operator from `!=` to `==`.