# The value of using string.find() is changed in while loop condition

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
   int pos;
   string str = "asd\t123";
   pos = str.find('\t');
   cout << pos <<endl;
   while (pos =str.find('\t') != string::npos) {
      cout << pos <<endl;
      break;
   }
   cout << pos <<endl;
   return 0;   
}
```

The output is 3 and 1. why would that happen if I put `pos = str.find()` in the while loop condition?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
while ( (pos = str.find('\t')) != string::npos)
{
...
}
```

The value is changed because `while (pos = str.find('\t') != string::npos)` is being interpreted as:

```
while (pos = (str.find('\t') != string::npos))
```

You are assigning the result of `(str.find('\t') != string::npos)`, which is `true` to `pos`. Since `pos` is an `int`, `true` gets converted to `1`.

As mentioned in the comments, you should turn on your wall warning flags, `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` and you will immediately get a warning. Try it here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67c5d326f70b9bc1

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and it will tell you this straight away!

Comment: Reminded me of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504181/quiz-does-this-compile-and-if-so-what-does-it-return-i-know-the-answer